# How to remove HTML tags in XML

Tags: java, html, string, xpath, tags

I have an XML having HTML tags for few fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Carmodels>
  <Cars>
    <id>1223</id>
    <car>Sedan</car>
    <price>1000</price>
  </Cars>
  <Cars>
    <id>1234</id>
    <car>Sports</car>
    <price>2500</price>
  </Cars>
  <Cars>
    <id>1123</id>
    <car>&lt;p&gt;Taxi 1&lt;/p&gt;</car>
    <price>9000</price>
  </Cars>
  <Cars>
    <id>1223</id>
    <car>&lt;p&gt;Taxi 2&lt;/p&gt;</car>
    <price>1000</price>
  </Cars>
</Carmodels>
```

when I extract `<car>` from xml using xpath `//cars[id = '1223']/car` and keep it in Java string, the value is populated as

```
 <p>Taxi 2</p>
```

When I try .replace() to remove

tags, I am unable to remove them. Can you help me how to remove these tags.

Comment: How did you try to remove those tags with replace()?

Comment: .replace("<p>","").replace("</p>",""); and .replace("&lt;p&gt;","").replace("&lt;/p&gt;","");

Comment: Use `/text()` at the end of your XPath expression or use a regex to clean your string with `replaceAll`. `String data = "<p>Taxi 2</p>"; clean = data.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "")`